# JQuery loop through array for the right button

Tags: jquery

I currently have this working code:

```
 $('#imgX').on('click', function(){
    $('table#newspaper-a tr:has(td.X)').toggle();
});
```

My question is, is it possible to maken an array from 1-100 (for the value of X) and loop throught it to see if a button is clicked?
Because I have a button on every td with a name 'img1' 'img2' and I want that button to toggle the td's with the same number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be better adding a `data-` attribute to try and identify the correct image:

**HTML**

```
<img src="whatever.jpg" data-idx="1" alt="My Image" />
<img src="whatever.jpg" data-idx="2" alt="My Image" />
<img src="whatever.jpg" data-idx="3" alt="My Image" />
<img src="whatever.jpg" data-idx="4" alt="My Image" />
<img src="whatever.jpg" data-idx="5" alt="My Image" />
<table id="newspaper-a">
    <tr>
        <td class="td1">1</td>
        <td class="td2">2</td>
        <td class="td3">3</td>
        <td class="td4">4</td>
        <td class="td5">5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('img').on('click', function(){
    $('table#newspaper-a tr:has(td.td' + $(this).data("idx") + ')').toggle();
});
```

Also, CSS classes cannot start with a number, so you would need to prefix the `idx` with something. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/kjLbb/) is a fiddle to demonstrate the above.

Comment: The buttons are indeed responding to the right tds now, thanks for that! But this is only togglinh the tds with the same number, i meant to toggle the whole row where that td is in!

Comment: @BjornBogers Missed that requirement, updated answer with the selector from your question

Comment: Is there a way to hide all the involved tds by the way?

Answer (score 0):

Looping through all the tds is not a good idea. What if you have 1000 rows or something like that. I'll suggest to use script like this:

```
$("#yourbutton").on("click", function() {
   $(this).parent().toggle();
});
```

I.e. *.parent()* selects the td which the buttons is part of.

P.S.
You should really try to optimize your selectors. Yours looks a bit crazy.

Comment: I don't think in OP's situation the `td`s are parents of the `buttons`. otherwise, once hidden, there would be no way to show them again...